# How to connect to remote elasticsearch server which is UP and Started using elasticsearch java client

Tags: java, elasticsearch

i am using this code to connect my local elastic server

```
        String url = "localhost:9200";
        String encodedUrl = URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8");
        Node node = nodeBuilder().settings(
                Settings.settingsBuilder()
                        .put("http.enabled", false)
                        .put("path.home", encodedUrl)
        )
                .client(true)
                .data(false)
                .node();
        return node.client();
```

I am using this code to connect remote elastic server

```
       // Transport client way


        Settings settings = Settings.settingsBuilder()
                .put("cluster.name", "Test") // remote elastic cluster name which is different in my case
                .build();
        Client client = TransportClient.builder().settings(settings).build()
                .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("**.**.***.**"), 9259)); // my remote elastic server IP and its port 
        return client;


       // And my other way of connecting (Node Client way)is


       String url = "**.**.***.**:9259";

        String encodedUrl = URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8");
        Node node = nodeBuilder().settings(
                Settings.settingsBuilder()
                        .put("http.enabled", false)
                        .put("path.home", encodedUrl)
                        .put("discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts", "52.74.***.**")
                        .put("cluster.name", "Test")
        )
                .client(true)
                .data(false)
                .node();
        return node.client();
```

I am able to connect my local elastic server but i am unable to connect to remote elastic server, there were always some errors coming

NodeNotConnectedException:

SendRequestTransportException

ReceiveTimeoutTransportException

NodeNotAvailableException:

etc...

Can anyone help me to figure out how to connect to remote elastic server using java, as i am developing web applications in dropwizard framework and need to get data from these elastic api servers

while establishing a client connection with remote ES server this thing happens

```
INFO  [2016-04-13 11:23:45,826] org.elasticsearch.node: [Thunderbolt] version[2.2.0], pid[4720], build[8ff36d1/2016-01-27T13:32:39Z]
INFO  [2016-04-13 11:23:45,826] org.elasticsearch.node: [Thunderbolt] initializing ...
INFO  [2016-04-13 11:23:45,826] org.elasticsearch.plugins: [Thunderbolt] modules [], plugins [], sites []
INFO  [2016-04-13 11:23:46,039] org.elasticsearch.node: [Thunderbolt] initialized
INFO  [2016-04-13 11:23:46,039] org.elasticsearch.node: [Thunderbolt] starting ...
INFO  [2016-04-13 11:23:46,732] org.elasticsearch.transport: [Thunderbolt] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9302}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:9302}, {[::1]:9302}
INFO  [2016-04-13 11:23:46,732] org.elasticsearch.discovery: [Thunderbolt] Test/eZo2PDQuTcWdd3zsLzVm-w
WARN  [2016-04-13 11:24:16,748] org.elasticsearch.discovery: [Thunderbolt] waited for 30s and no initial state was set by the discovery
INFO  [2016-04-13 11:24:16,748] org.elasticsearch.node: [Thunderbolt] started
```

Comment: What version of ES are you running?

Comment: Its 2.2.1 on windows

Answer (score 2):

Since ES 2.x, the ES server will [only bind to localhost by default](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking_20_network_changes.html#_bind_to_localhost), which means it is not reachable from the outside.

So on your remote ES server, make sure that your `elasticsearch.yml` configuration file contains the following `network.host` setting with a publicly reachable IP address:

```
network.host: a.b.c.d
```

where `a.b.c.d` is the IP address of your remote server.

Make sure to restart ES after making the change.

Comment: ya i can get the data from remote ES server in postman and chrome but i cant bind it in my java code as i did to my local server

Comment: What do you have as `network.host` setting and what do you use in your client code?

Comment: Its the IP address which is configured 52.74.***.** and in the client i am trying to get the data which is indexed

Comment: So you confirm that you can connect using `curl -XGET 52.74.***.**:9259` but not from within your Java code? Are you sure the cluster name `Test` matches with your `cluster.name` setting in `elasticsearch.yml` ? Do you ming updating your question with the log output you get when starting up ES?

Comment: ya exactly that is my problem, i can get using curl and postman but not from java code and cluster name is same as in .yml file

Comment: Do you ming updating your question with the log output you get when starting up ES?

Comment: i updated my question by providing the log when starting up ES and i am using node client way approach while connecting to remote ES and i updated that too

Comment: According to your log (`publish_address {127.0.0.1:9302}`), your `network.host` setting is not a public IP address but localhost. Are you sure you restarted your node after changing your configuration?

Comment: You've seen my last comment, right? Can you update your question with the relevant network config from your `elasticsearch.yml` field?

Answer (score 0):

The answer i figured out is

```
Settings settings = Settings.settingsBuilder()
            .put("cluster.name", "Test") 
            .build();
Client client = TransportClient.builder().settings(settings).build()
            .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("**.**.***.**"), 9300)); // my remote elastic server IP and its port 
return client;
```